# Is it possible to run Message Dialog Box java in Mac's Terminal?

Tags: java, macos

Here is a simple Java program from textbook

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WelcomeInMessageDialogBox{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    // Display Welcome
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to Java!");
    }
}
```

And I put  WelcomeInMessageDialogBox.java on the desktop, and then at Terminal, I type

```
javac WelcomeInMessageDialogBox.java
java  WelcomeInMessageDialogBox
```

And it returns this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WelcomeInMessageDialogBox
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WelcomeInMessageDialogBox
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

What's going on? I have no problem with Hello World.java, is that possible to run Dialog Box java program in Mac's Terminal?

Comment: What package does `WelcomeInMessageDialogBox` reside in?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sir, how to check the package?

Comment: Does `WelcomeInMessageDialogBox` have a `package` statement, should be the first line of source code.  Also do a `ls` where you compiled the program from and check that the `.class` file exists

Comment: Also, make, sure you spell it correctly `java  WelcomeInMessageDialogBo` ... missing the `x` from `Box`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, it does not have package statement. And, there is no .class file exists. And I spell it correctly, sorry about that, I type it wrong in the question.

Comment: If there is no `.class` file then the file didn't compile...

Comment: @MadProgrammer then how can I create .class file? Does not javac create .class file? It works for Hello World and it creates Hello Wrold.class

Comment: Yes, that's how you compile classes, but for some reason, yours is not compiling, you need to find out why...

Comment: Works just fine for me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, I clean my desktop and suddenly everything is fine...strange java...